# How to create a nested list of comprehension for counting number of sheets in a list of excel files?

Tags: python, pandas

I created a loop for counting the number of sheets inside each excel file in my directory.

I tried to create a nested list of comprehension, but i don't know how to deal with the `pd.ExcelFile(file)` that actually works inside my loop

In order to simplify the code here I created a list containing all the files inside the folder.

```
 file_list=['file1.xlsx','file2.xlsx','file3.xlsx','file4.xlsx']
 counter=[] 
 for file in file_list: 
      xl=pd.ExcelFile(file)
      res=len(xl.sheet_names)
      counter.append(res)
```

I was looking for something like this:

```
  result=[counter.append(i) for file in file_list for i len(y.sheet_names)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the list comprehension version, you may always add your `for x in i` in the `[]` then on the left compute something, and if needed add a condition at the right

```
counter = [len(pd.ExcelFile(file).sheet_names) for file in file_list]
```